# What is the difference between len() and count() in python?

Tags: python, methods

look at this code :

```
x=object()
x_list=[x]*5
print x_list.count(x)
5
print len(x_list)
5
```

The output of `count()` and `len()` is same, What is the difference between them?

Comment: Now do `x_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]` and use `x_list.count(1)`.

Comment: @LukasGraf Why bother reading the documentation when you can always find someone to answer trivial questions here in the hope of of rep gain? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254433/should-i-send-students-to-stack-overflow/254436#254436

Comment: @msw: so helping someone is now verboten on the grounds that anyone who answers a question you find too trivial *must* be doing it for rep gain?

Comment: @msw: Python docs are excellent but also are too information dense when you are new to programming; and the `list` method docs *are* somewhat hidden. Lukas Graf had to link to the tutorial rather than the standard type docs because there are no direct links and the methods are grouped under 'sequence types' instead.

Comment: @msw my issue with the question isn't so much that it's trivial, but that it's motivated by trying to **guess APIs**, which is a horrible approach to programming (and IMHO should be discouraged, hence my snarky comment). I have to agree with Martijn Pieters though, while generally excellent, the Python *reference* docs are sometimes a bit lacking in that respect.

Comment: The number of instances of wrong answers given by neophytes to neophytes has been growing at least arithmetically and these are often given no attention at all, thus never get closed nor downvoted. It was to these I was referring. The answer below does add useful pedagogic assistance so I was *not* referring to that, just the general phenomenon.

Comment: @msw: don't worry, I do downvote wrong or otherwise unhelpful answers whenever I come across them, together with a comment as to why it was downvoted. Neophytes answering with bad advice do not come away unscathed when I find such answers.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`list.count()` counts how many times the given value appears. You created a list of 5 elements that are **all the same**, so of course `x_list.count()` finds that element 5 times in a list of length 5.

You could have tried the same test with a list with a *mix* of values:

```
>>> sample = [2, 10, 1, 1, 5, 2]
>>> len(sample)
6
>>> sample.count(1)
2
```

The `sample` list contains 6 elements, but the value `1` appears only twice.

Answer (score 0):

length method= len()
=> It's return number of element from value of variable.

count method = count()
=>It's return how many times  appeared from value of variable which you are specified value.

Let's take example of it:-

len() =>

list1 = ["Breakfast", "Lunch", "Snack", "Dinner"]

length1 = len(list1)

print(length1)

Output:-
4

Because in "list1" which has total value inside is 4.
So that's why it becomes output 4 by using len() method.

count()  =>

list1 = ["Breakfast", "Lunch", "Snack", "Dinner", "Snack"]

count_number = list1.count("Snack")

print(count_number)

Output =>
2

Because "snack" value is appear 2 times in your value of list.

Comment: This does not really bring any new info that is not contained in accepted answer.